# How to remove function?

Tags: actions

I'm trying to remove a function that is defined in my parent theme but can't get it to work. The function I want to remove prints previous/next post navigation.

Here's the function:

```
add_action( 'generate_after_entry_content', 'generate_footer_meta' );
function generate_footer_meta()
{
if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : ?>
    <footer class="entry-meta">
        <?php generate_entry_meta(); ?>
        <?php if ( is_single() ) generate_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>
    </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
<?php endif;
}
```

I'm using the `remove_action( );` function but I'm not sure which action hook to use.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
function remove_nav_links() {
remove_action( 'generate_after_entry_content', 'generate_footer_meta' );
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'remove_nav_links' );
```

I've tried a few different action hooks including `wp_footer` but none have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you want to remove this *after* it had been added, but *before* that hook fires. Which is hard to tell in general without knowing *when* does the parent theme executes this.

Also in often confusing way `functions.php` of child theme is loaded *before* that of parent theme. Often makes timing of things counter–intuitive.

The very *general* practice is that you wait until `init` hook to run any logic, other than strictly related to the load process. So my *guess* would be on/around `init`, but really you should figure out when is it added and decide based on that.

Comment: Thanks, I tried `init` and it worked. Should have tried that first! I found [this article](http://rachievee.com/the-wordpress-hooks-firing-sequence/) helpful to gaining a better understanding of action hooks.